# Making a darker color with the blackness color function?

Tags: html, css, postcss

I'd like to use the CSS color function `blackness()` to make a dark color 20% darker.  If I try it out on [colorme.io](https://colorme.io/) with the color `#343a40` and setting `blackness` to 20% the color does not turn darker, but ends up being this blue color `#3380cc`.  Here is a picture:

[image]

So is `blackness(%)` the right function and is there perhaps a different way to apply it to achieve the result I'm looking for.  I may want to take a spectrum of color and make them all 20% darker and 40% darker ...

Answer (score 1):

css hsl() may help you.

## 343a40 = hsl(210, 10%, 23%)

The last 23% is lightness.

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp?colorhex=343a40

Comment: It almost looks as if we need to know the color and percentages we want first, and then we can play with the percentage from there .... I was hoping for something where we can say that we want it to be 20% darker, in general across any spectrum of colors ...

Comment: For your request, Sass/Less function can do it. https://codepen.io/baudoin/pen/HdliD

Comment: Yes I've played with those and there is a sass postcss color function ... but it does not play well with version 6.0 ... I think because the plugins should be peer dependencies ... So I had to use the postcss-color-functions plugin ... which only has the w3c functions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `shade(%)` instead of `blackness()` and `tint(%)` instead of lightness.  The changes were [committed to this repository file](https://github.com/superflycss/variables-colors/blob/master/src/main/css/notifications/index.css) in case anyone wants to see a postcss example. Here's a sample:

```
    --color-primary-100: color(var(--color-primary) tint(var(--percentage-40)));
    --color-primary-300: color(var(--color-primary) tint(var(--percentage-20)));
    --color-primary-500: var(--color-primary);
    --color-primary-700: color(var(--color-primary) shade(var(--percentage-20)));
    --color-primary-900: color(var(--color-primary) shade(var(--percentage-40)));
```

Also added a [test case here](https://superflycss.github.io/component-button/target/test/html/bootstrap/index.html) where I used the 700 level color for the hover on Bootstrap buttons.